# Kafka Mirror Maker With Azure Event Hub

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-eventhub

Working on hybrid cloud solution of data movement from on premise to cloud and want to achieve Mirror Maker from Apache kafka on premise with Azure Event Hub in cloud?

Any specific version of Kafka if it possible?

Comment: It should be possible from any recent version of Kafka as long as Azure is compatible... Are you having any problems when you try it?

Comment: Checking the feasibility for the solution, hence understand any compatibility issues

Comment: Well, it doesn't hurt to try it, then you wouldn't have to ask, no?

Comment: It works and the configuration is pretty simple, here is the helpful link: https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs/tree/master/samples/kafka/mirror-maker

Comment: Rather than leave a comment, feel free to put that as an answer below with an example configuration file and command. Note: MirrorMaker can be limiting, so Kafka Connect could be used instead https://github.com/salesforce/mirus